# what are $SSE$ and $S_{y,x}$?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I'm a BC student who is trying to solve some statistic quizzes.

there is a multiple choice question that is this:

> In a simple regression model $y=a+bx+e$ our given data is this:
>   $$ \bar{x} = 2, \bar{y} = 3, S_x = 4, S_y = 5, r = 0.6 $$ find
>   SSE and $S_{y,x}$.
>
> 1. $16, 4$
> 2. $14, 4$
> 3. $4, 14$
> 4. $4, 16$

I must confess I have no idea what is a $S_{y,x}$! but for SSE here is my work *(I've assumed that $s_y$ is the sum of all $y$)*:

\begin{align}
\text{SSE} = (1-r^2) \text{SST} &= (1-r^2)\sum(y-\bar y)^2 \\
&= (1-r^2) \left(\sum y^2  -\frac{(\sum y)^2}n \right) \\
&= (1-r^2)\left(\sum y^2 -\frac{S^2_y}n \right) \\
&= (1-r^2)\left( \sum y^2 -\frac{S^2_y}{\left. S_y \middle/ \bar y \right.} \right) \\
&= (1-r^2)\left( \sum y^2 -S_y \bar y \right)
\end{align}

but in this case, I can't find $\sum y^2$. I want some help.

thank in advance.

Comment: Do you have the sample size $n$? For $S_{y,x}$ I would have guessed that this is the covariance for the sample but $S_{y,x}=rS_xS_y=12$ is not a value from the possible answers.

Comment: @MachineLearner no, All the information that is given is that. it is not clear for me too. but I know that the answer is number 1. we can find $n$ by $\frac{S_y}{\bar y}$ but it is 5/3 and not an integer! I'm so confused. may $S_y$ is not the sum.

Comment: You cannot find $n$ by $S_y/\bar{y}$ (if $S_y$ is the sample variance). You could use $\bar{y}=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$ but you don't have the sum either.

Comment: @MachineLearner OMG! I'd thought that $S_y$ is the sum of all $y$. thank you for that information. now I can think about the problem again.

Comment: I wanted to say $S^2_y$ is the sample variance. The square is important.

Comment: @MachineLearner isn't $S^2_y = SST = n Var(y)$? becuase $(1-0.36)(25) = 16$ that is the right answer. :-?